# Using jQueryMobile AND bootstrap together

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fuelphp

Right now I'm building a web app, and I would like the device to use jquerymobile for resolutions under 780 pixels, and bootstrap for above 780 pixels.. Is this even possible? I've tried searching around and I can't figure out a solution. I would like to use bits and pieces of both, the problem is this strongly conflict with each other... I don't want to build two separate sites because that would ruin the responsiveness.

Twitter bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
jQueryMobile: http://jquerymobile.com

Here's my head...

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php echo Asset::js('jquery.js'); ?>
    <?php echo Asset::css('bootstrap.min.css'); ?>
    <?php echo Asset::js('bootstrap.min.js'); ?>
    <?php echo Asset::css('bootstrap-responsive.css'); ?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply switch to jQM from Bootstrap (or the opposite) on window resize without sending the user to a different page all together due to the differences in markup javascript and css between the two libraries. You could however have bootstrap display a button for the lower resolution screens that will take them to the jQM version of your site.

Another option is on page load, check device width and do a redirect.

Comment: Would it be possible to break the bootstrap link if the screen size is too small? Would that only work with the initial load, or would that work dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean by break it? Also, did you know that bootstrap has a responsive stylesheet that makes it work very well in mobile devices? It automatically resizes the document and it's structure to best fit the current screen size if you setup the structure correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[Adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs) might work well for you. It's a lightweight javascript that checks your window width and then serves the appropriate CSS. In theory you specify jquerymobile css for window widths under 780, and bootstrap above 780.

I've used adapt.js by itself before and it worked like a charm. Without actually putting the whole idea to the test I'm not sure if there would be any javascript conflicts or not though.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could try including the bootstrap css only for resolution over 780px

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:780px)">
<link href="bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:780px)">
```

As for jqueryMobile, it usually requires some markup, so you won't be able to enable/disable it with just media-queries

Answer (score 0):

You could also try my jQuery Mobile Bootstrap theme:

https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Bootstrap-Theme

It's hosted on Github and confirmed to work with the current version of jQuery Mobile (1.2).